# UITextView does not scroll in landscape mode (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITextView that scrolls just fine when phone is in Portrait but does not scroll when in landscape.

In both portraits and landscape, the content is scrolled to the bottom with the top lines out of the view.  In portrait I can scroll up to see the top but in landscape they are not accessible.

I have tried all of the following, one at a time and combined without any luck:

```
textview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
textview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
textview.contentSize = CGSize(width: 2 * textview.frame.size.width, height: 2 * textview.frame.size.height)
textview.isScrollEnabled = true
```

I tried putting them in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, again without success.

(I also tried `textview.contentSize = textview.bounds.size  * 2` but get error messages `Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'CGSize'` and  `Cannot convert value of type 'CGSize' to expected argument type 'Int'`.)

How do I get scrolling to work in landscape?

Answer (score 0):

Select device supported orientation, then OK

[image: 8888]

---

add following code to override operator, then OK to erase error messages

```
func *(size: CGSize, ratio: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: size.width * CGFloat(ratio), height: size.height * CGFloat(ratio))
}
```

Comment: Thank you dengST30 - it turned out to be a constraint issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**:

I first created a new project with only a UIView and a UITextField and found that it scrolled just fine in either portrait or landscape.

Thinking that something else was preventing the scrolling, I began deleting things.  After deleting the class to which the UIView belonged I noticed that the background color was different in portrait and landscape (in portrait the color was my storyboard color,m in landscape it was black).

Eventually, it turned out to be a constraint - in wide mode I had attempted to connect both the top and the bottom of a fixed height view to the views above and below that were separated by more space than that height.  (What I do not understand is why I did not get constraint error messages...)